# difference of two arrays in php, one with keys and another without

Tags: php, arrays

```
$a = array("a","b"); 
$b = array("a"=>"one", "b" => "two","c"=>"three");
```

I need help in finding the difference between two arrays one with key and another without key.

required output

```
"c"=>"three"
```

Comment: So did you bother looking at functions like [array_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: i tried array_diff it gives back me the full array

print_r(array_diff($b,$a));
o/p : Array ( [a] => one [b] => two [c] => three )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_diff_key()` and `array_flip()`:

```
$difference = array_diff_key(
    $b,
    array_flip($a)
);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/YgNhB

Comment: If this works for you, do you want to accept it as answer, too?

Comment: 'm new to stackoverflow.. how to accept it or wat i shd do?

Answer (score 0):

Every array has keys. Even if you have not set them.

So, your arrays look like this:

```
$a = array(0=>"a",1=>"b"); 
$b = array("a"=>"one", "b" => "two","c"=>"three");
```

And you trying to compare the **values** of one array with the **keys** of the other.

That's why localheinz is using `array_flip()` in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45586445/7467567).